# What happens to the atlas when a league ends?

Tags: path-of-exile

I am currently participating in the Legacy league (softcore).

Despite my main character is in Standard, I still have not completed the atlas.

I now find myself in Legacy with a few maps that never dropped in Standard, and thus I never completed.

What happens if I complete the bonus objectives in Legacy? Will I retain them when Legacy ends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every bonus objective is treated separately. You retain every bonus objective that you had in Standard, and retain every bonus objective that you obtained during Legacy.

[Other merge rules:](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Atlas_of_Worlds#End_of_league_transfer)

- Sextant mods are kept, parent league mods have a priority in conflict
- Shaped maps are kept, parent league has priority in conflict